What does "I do" mean in this context?
In the movie "Nightwish" there is a foolish man, when somebody asks something from him, he always says the same thing:
"Wendall guards the property,, Wendall locks the gate,Wendall feeds the animals, and Wendall calls the house. I do"
There is another word for "I do"?

It's not meant to be standard English, more childish speech. "I do," by itself, is relevant only as reply to a question, e.g., "Do you diet?" "I do."

Wendall must be speaking: Wendall does these things. That's me.

Thank you very much!

This is something unusual that's part of a movie dialog. To me it indicates that Wendall might be mentally challenged and speak in a child-like manner sometimes.
Wendall is speaking in the third person about himself (Wendall guards the property, etc.). He changes to the first person at the end and says "I do," apparently clarifying who Wendall is. It means that "I do all these things."
There's not another word for "I do." There are alternative ways to express the same idea, such as:

I am Wendall. I do all these things.
Guess who Wendall is? It's me. I do everything.


Thank you for the explanation. Yes, he is mentally challanged. At 20:05 https://youtu.be/ZDm8wPSiBG0?si=6CH5yRV0pKlYY9vV
